# Is there a way to test and debug DAGs from a local device to Composer Cloud?

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I want to deploy and edit Airflow DAGs from local and find errors without going to upload DAGs.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to run local Airflow environments with the Composer Local Development CLI tool:

1. Install the Composer Local Development CLI tool

```bash
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/composer-local-dev.git
pip install .
```

2. Create a local Airflow environment from your Cloud Composer environment

```bash
composer-dev create LOCAL_ENV_NAME \
  --from-source-environment CLOUD_ENV_NAME \
  --location CLOUD_ENV_REGION \
  --project GCP_PROJECT_ID \
  --port 8081 \
  --dags-path LOCAL_DAGS_DIRECTORY
```

3. Start the local environment

```bash
composer-dev start LOCAL_ENV_NAME
```

4. Run Airflow commands to trigger dag runs, e.g.

```bash
composer-dev run-airflow-cmd LOCAL_ENV_NAME dags trigger DAG_ID
```

or go to the Airflow's UI at `localhost:8081` to trigger dags manually.

More information can be found in this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/run-local-airflow-environments).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Answer (score 0):

You are able to test a single instance in a local environment and see the log output; viewing the output enables you to check for syntax errors and task errors that might occur, but note that testing in a local environment does not check dependencies or communication status to the database.

I would recommend you to put the DAGs in a data/test folder in your test environment and follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/testing-dags#test-directory) that Google provides.